# The Input in Jupyter Python doesn't do anything for me

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter, I'm getting this  `[ * ]`, and it won't let me input. For an example,

```
name = input('What is your name?\n')
```

I get no respond or the output.

Comment: Hi -- `this [*]` isn't enough for us to help you. Please post your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to improve your question. This helps you getting better and faster answers.

Comment: In Jupyter `[*]` means the cell is busy, either doing some computation, or waiting for an input. If a cell is stuck, you might want to restart your Kernel (in Kernel menu, choose Restart & Clear Output).